# How to use Symfony2 Security standalone?

Tags: security, symfony, acl, roles

Documentation says it is a standalone component.

Given I have following yaml parsed in the empty index.php file, how to init security and check roles etc.?

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    providers:
        default_provider:
            memory:
                users:
                    ryan:  { password: ryanpass, roles: 'ROLE_USER' }
                    admin: { password: kitten, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Matthias Noback](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415496/matthias-noback) hat just writed some documentation about the Security Component. You can read the raw version [on github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/1604/files), but it will be merged soon and aviable for you at http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/introduction.html

Or you can read his blog posts about the Security Component before changing it to documentation: http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/category/security/

Comment: Looks promising. I'm not sure if it will work without Kernel. We'll see.

Comment: Last URL is broken. The correct one is http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/categories/Security/